# Combine Object/Array using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How do you combine two objects like this?

```
const target = { year1 : {}, year2: {somevalue2...}};
const source = { year1 : {somevalue1...}, year2: {} };
```

expected Input:

```
{ year1 : {somevalue1}, year2 : {somevalue2} }
```

Thank you!

Comment: what if target and source have both a value for year1 or year2 ? do we want to combine them ?

Comment: try this?                                                                                                                          let output= {
    ...year1,
    ...year2
};

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two objects while keeping matching keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735236/merging-two-objects-while-keeping-matching-keys)

Comment: If `target.year2`'s content should merge with and not overwrite `source.year2`, then you'll want a recursive (deep) merge. You can find a lot of information (and examples) in the answers to the following question: [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Comment: @Hunter ... of cause not since there is only `target` and `source` and in addition each features a direct `year1` and `year2` property. Thus it is not clear what ... `let output= { ...year1, ...year2 };` actually is good for and/or refers to. And regarding the useful flags of this comment, was there at least more than one second thinking about the proposed solution and its correctness/validity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash [_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge)

```js
const target = { year1 : {}, year2: {s:1}}
const source = { year1 : {s:2}, year2: {} }
const result = _.merge(target, source);
console.log('result', result)
// => { year1 : {s:2}, year2: {s:1}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yo Thank you for your answer!.

I think I forgot to mention that the objects are in array. I'm getting the data from an API which have this weird setup.


Thank you dude! You save my dying brain cells lmao :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `Array#reduce` a way to look at `{}` as `null` as in the following demo:

```js
const target = { year1 : {}, year2: {somekey2:"somevalue2"}};
const source = { year1 : {somekey1:"somevalue1"}, year2: {} };

//A function to convert any {} to null
const e2Null = obj => 
  obj && 
  Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && 
  obj.constructor === Object ? 
  null : obj;

const output = [source,target]
    .reduce((acc,cur) => Object.keys(cur)
        .reduce((a,c) => ({...a,[c]:acc[c] ?? e2Null(cur[c])}), {}),{}
    );

console.log( output );
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's `.isEmptyObject(...)` method as follows:

```js
const target = { year1 : {}, year2: {somekey2:"somevalue2"}};
const source = { year1 : {somekey1:"somevalue1"}, year2: {} };

const e2Null = obj => jQuery.isEmptyObject(obj) ? null : obj

const output = [source,target]
    .reduce((acc,cur) => Object.keys(cur)
        .reduce((a,c) => ({...a,[c]:acc[c] ?? e2Null(cur[c])}), {}),{}
    );
    
console.log( output );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can recursively iterate over all the properties of `target` and `source` using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and copy the properties that you want to the `source` or to a new object.

Something like that:

```
const combine = (target, source) => {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(source)) {
    // here you copy the `value` to `target[key]` or
    // if the value is an object you can call `combine()` recursively
    // on the `value` and `target[key]`
  }
}
```